How can I draw inner vertical line centered in tabular?
I want to centered drawn inner vertical line in tabular.
Example code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{R} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & C1 & C2                                           \\ \hline
  r1                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
  r2                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Its output:


Wanted output: If possible, I want C1 and C2 column equally splitted.
---------------------------------
|R |No. Jobs Completed/Submitted|
|r1|     C1      |     C2       |
|-------------------------------|
|r2|      a      |      b       |
--------------------------------



You can use the w-column type from array package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|w{c}{3cm}|w{c}{3cm}|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{R} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & C1 & C2                                           \\ \hline
  r1                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
  r2                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


PS: It is recommended to use \extrarowheight provided by array so that the table looks better.

Where can I use \extrarowheight ?

See the modified answer@alper

With the tabularray package, you could use the hspan=even option to distribute the columns evenly:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c|c|c|},
  hspan=even
}
  \hline
  \SetCell[r=2]{} R & \SetCell[c=2]{} No. Jobs Completed/Submitted & \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & C1 & C2                                           \\ \hline
  r1                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
  r2                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



with nicematrix
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}[width=0.6\linewidth]{cX[c]X[c]}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
        \Block{2-1}{R} & \Block{1-2}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} & \\
        & C1 & C2 \\
        r1 & a & b \\
        r2 & a & b \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    or
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c W{c}{3cm} W{c}{3cm}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
        \Block{2-1}{R} & \Block{1-2}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} & \\
        & C1 & C2 \\
        r1 & a & b \\
        r2 & a & b \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}



Since you use the tabluarx tag, here is a solution using this package
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{R} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & C1 & C2                                           \\ \hline
  r1                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
  r2                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}

The 0.6\texwidth is the width of the table, it could be ajusted to fit your need.

The same in spirit as the answer by Stephen, but using the natural width of your table header by measuring it:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, array}

\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}
\settowidth\mylength{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted}
\mylength=.5\dimexpr\mylength-\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax
\begin{tabular}{|c|*2{w{c}{\mylength}|}}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{R} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & C1 & C2                                           \\ \hline
  r1                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
  r2                 & a  & b                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



An, imho, prettified version of your table by dropping all the vertical rules and using booktabs horizontal ones:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, array}

\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}
\settowidth\mylength{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted}
\mylength=.5\dimexpr\mylength-2\tabcolsep\relax
\begin{tabular}{c*2{w{c}{\mylength}}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{R} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{No. Jobs Completed/Submitted} \\
                     & C1 & C2                                          \\
  \midrule
  r1                 & a  & b                                           \\
  r2                 & a  & b                                           \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


