Centering a group of table columns under a wide header
In the following table, the "Mean agreement vs. random" column is logically just one column, but it needs a bunch of internal alignment: the decimal points are supposed to all line up, and so are the inequality signs. In order to make that internal alignment happen, I've split it up into five columns plus two more for padding, because "Mean agreement vs. random" is a lot wider than the inequalities.  I'm happy with that part as is.
The actual problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to make the padding columns auto-size themselves so that the block of inequalities appears, overall, to be centered under the header.  Right now I have manual fixed-width padding using m columns, which I can make look good enough by manual adjustment, but that's tedious and has to be adjusted if I change the overall layout again.
I tried changing the m column specs to m{0pt plus1fill}, but the "plus1fill" is not recognized as part of the width spec and shows up embedded in the table instead.  I also tried using c for the padding columns, with \hspace{\fill} in the top cells of both; that causes the inequalities to be flush left under their header.
Suggestions?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
% approximate \thickmuskip outside math mode
\def\relskip{\hskip 0.27778em plus0.27778em\relax}
\begin{tabular}[b]{lrm{2.5em}@{}r@{.}l@{\relskip}c@{\relskip}r@{.}l@{}m{1.5em}}
\toprule
  \textbf{Type} &
  \textbf{\# clusters} &
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Mean agreement vs. random}} \\
\midrule
\textbf{ASes}       & 534 & & 99 & 28\% & $>$   & 99 & 20\% & \\
\textbf{Cities}     & 481 & & 99 & 62   & $>$   & 98 & 99   & \\
\textbf{Countries}  &  96 & & 93 & 88   & $\ll$ & 96 & 32   & \\
\textbf{Continents} &   6 & & 83 & 08   & $<$   & 84 & 05   & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



The S column from siunitx can handle the decimal points.  Note that the excess width from the \multicolumn will all wind up in the last column.

@JohnKormylo I know about siunitx (and dcolumn). I'm asking about how to get the block of inequalities aligned as a whole under the column header, not about better ways to handle decimal point alignment.

beware m columns, they have their uses but you lose baseline alignment so are not usually suitable for this kind of table.

@zwol You could use tabularray and use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716860/how-can-i-draw-inner-vertical-line-centered-in-tabular/716864#716864

From the number you present, I'd guess that all those in the Mean agreement vs. random column are percentages, you should reflect that "unit" in the table's head, not just on the first row of the values. Also note that for most units there should be a small space between number and unit, so you should use 99.28\,\%.

@Skillmon How would you word the column head for that?

Mean agreement vs. random (in \%) (though that shared column head with the relation in between the columns destroys that a bit -- "correct" would be something like Mean agreement vs. random / \% or Mean agreement / \% vs. random / \%). But if you don't put the unit in the table header you'd have to continue it in each row, not only the first...

This computes the space needed to center the columns w.r.t the \multicolumn.  I should confess that the -\tabcolsep is more of a fudge factor since I can't figure out why it is needed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newlength{\myspace}
\begin{document}
% approximate \thickmuskip outside math mode
\bgroup
  \sbox0{\textbf{Mean agreement vs. random}}
  \sbox1{\begin{tabular}{S@{}c@{}S}
    99.28\% & $>$ & 99.20\%
  \end{tabular}}% one row will do
  \global\myspace=\dimexpr 0.5\wd0-0.5\wd1-\tabcolsep\relax
\egroup
\begin{tabular}[b]{lr p{\myspace} S @{}c@{} Sl}
\toprule
  \textbf{Type} &
  \textbf{\# clusters} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Mean agreement vs. random}} \\
\midrule
\textbf{ASes}       & 534 & & 99.28\% & $>$   & 99.20\% & \\
\textbf{Cities}     & 481 & & 99.62   & $>$   & 98.99   & \\
\textbf{Countries}  &  96 & & 93.88   & $\ll$ & 96.32   & \\
\textbf{Continents} &   6 & & 83.08   & $<$   & 84.05   & \\
\bottomrule
&&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Please note that by convention the scratch registers with uneven numbers should be used global and those with even numbers local, so you should use \sbox2 instead of \sbox1 here.

The -\tabcolsep is necessary because in your \sbox1 you have one \tabcolsep on either side of your table, but between your filler p-column and the first content column you got two \tabcolsep, and you have to compensate for that. Or in other words, your header is <sep><5 columns including their inter-seps><sep>, your measurement uses <sep>ScS<sep>, and your real usages is then <sep>p<sep><sep>ScS<sep> being one <sep> too much compared to what you measured and need to compensate.

@skillmon - As long as you don't use any commands which follow that (awful) convention, you will be fine.  Just don't inflict global registers 0-9 on anyone else.  And thanks for the explanation.

Well, in your case it might be fine, but it might mess with the safe-stack giving worse performance for no reason if you used one macro which followed that convention. You don't have to agree with the convention, but answers here should reflect best practice, which includes following the established conventions (I don't particularly like them as well, and think that global assignments are very seldomly needed anyways...).

Accepting this answer since I wound up using this fundamental technique, but I also cribbed a lot of ideas from the other answers.

I would probably use fewer alignment points:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\p{\phantom{\%}}
\begin{tabular}{lr@{\qquad}r@{}>{${}}l<{{}$}@{}l}
\toprule
  \textbf{Type} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\# clusters}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\textbf{Mean agreement}}&
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{vs. random}} \\
\midrule
\textbf{ASes}       & 534 & 99.28\% & >&  99.20\%  \\
\textbf{Cities}     & 481 & 99.62\p & >&  98.99    \\
\textbf{Countries}  &  96 & 93.88\p &\ll& 96.32    \\
\textbf{Continents} &   6 & 83.08\p &  <& 84.05    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


This is nice and simple but, uh, the inequalities are not actually centered relative to "Mean agreement vs. random".

@zwol I know: basically they are aligned on the "vs", makes more sense to me (and was easier) but others can answer with different layouts. If the tick goes to someone else, I'll survive:-)

I'd shorten the header.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  >{$}c<{$}
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}
  }
\toprule
Type &
{\# clusters} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Mean agreement \\ vs.\ random (\%)\end{tabular}%
} \\
\midrule
ASes       & 534 & 99.28 & >   & 99.20 \\
Cities     & 481 & 99.62 & >   & 98.99 \\
Countries  &  96 & 93.88 & \ll & 96.32 \\
Continents &   6 & 83.08 & <   & 84.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}



The following code combines the idea of precalculating the table width by John Kormylo and tabularray. Also, table preamble specifies: font for the first row and column (no need to use \textbf in all the cells), math type for the column with inequality signs (with adding {} at the beginning and at the end to use usual math spacing around binary relations) and removes gaps between columns with numbers and inequality signs. The numbers are formatted using siunitx, though it's unnecessary here (using l columns would suffice).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\newdimen\myspace

\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \sbox0{%
  \begin{booktabs}{
    colspec={lll},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  }
  Continents & \# clusters & Mean agreement vs. random \\
  \end{booktabs}%
  }
  \global\myspace=\wd0
\egroup

\begin{booktabs}[
  baseline=b,
]{
  width={\myspace},
  colspec={lrXS[table-format=2.2{\%}]cS[table-format=2.2{\%}]X},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  column{1}={font=\bfseries},
  column{5}={mode=math,preto={{}},appto={{}},colsep=0pt},
  column{4}={rightsep=0pt},
  column{6}={leftsep=0pt},
  cell{1}{3}={c=5}{c},
}
\toprule
Type & \# clusters & Mean agreement vs. random \\
\midrule
ASes       & 534 & & 99.28\% & >   & 99.20\% & \\
Cities     & 481 & & 99.62   & >   & 98.99   & \\
Countries  &  96 & & 93.88   & \ll & 96.32   & \\
Continents &   6 & & 83.08   & <   & 84.05   & \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}

The result:

